# CMAKE: Environment variable not available in "make test"

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, environment-variables

I set an environment variable in the Unit test's CMakeList.txt:

```
set(ENV{UNIT_TEST_FOLDER_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

IF(DEFINED ENV{UNIT_TEST_FOLDER_PATH})
    MESSAGE(STATUS "UNIT_TEST_FOLDER_PATH env seen: --[$ENV{UNIT_TEST_FOLDER_PATH}]--")
ELSE()
    MESSAGE(STATUS "UNIT_TEST_FOLDER_PATH not seen")
ENDIF()
```

When I do:

```
cmake3 --test .
```

It prints the status message:

```
UNIT_TEST_FOLDER_PATH env seen: --[/home/ssk/..]
```

But when I do:

```
make test
```

It's not able to access the UNIT_TEST_FOLDER_PATH variable in the code using std::getenv.

How to persist the environment variable during the "make test" step?

Comment: Based on the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-environment-variable), the environment variable only applies to the *current* CMake process, not subsequent processes. You could use something like [`configure_file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) to copy your environment variable path into your source code directly, removing the need for `std::getenv`.